# extracting data using regex

Tags: regex, typescript

I want to extract the productname and the price. the orc'd result which is the product name and price is not on the same line. so how do i include the line before the price?

*sample structure of product from receipt:*

```
RETAIL
UPRICE QTY TOTAL
ILLUSTRATION BOARD 15X20 (1/4 SIZE ) BY
1276
12.50 1.0 12.50
MONGOL PENCIL 1,2,3 PC
434
6.50 1.0 6.50
MS 300 (MGK) PERMANENT MARKER
1470
3.75 1.0 3.75
HBW White Glue 40 grans
1690
10.00 1.0 10.00
COLOR PEN 8 COLORS (VARIOUS BRAND)
1930
16.50 1.0 16.50
KS /CREATION CONSTRUCTION PAPER (105)
3503
23.00 1.0 23.00
```

this is the regex that i've tried but the result doesn't include the product name, only the price. this.result contains data(sample given above) from receipt

**ts file**

```
   this.result = {
      merchant: text.split("\n")[0],
      product: text.split("\n").filter(t => t.match(/([\w\s]+)(\d+\.\d{2})/))
   };
```

**html file**

```
 <ion-card *ngIf="result">
    <ion-card-content>
      <p>Results:</p>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Merchant</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" value="{{result.merchant}}"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item *ngFor="let product of result.product; let i = index">
        <ion-label>Product #{{i+1}}</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" value="{{product}}"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
```

Comment: Your pattern alone works (kinda), so if you're only seeing the numbers on the right and not the text on the left as well, the problem is elsewhere - can you post a full [MCVE]?

Comment: the data im trying to extract is from my ocr'd result using cloud vision.i don't know where and what went wrong. everything works just fine. except for the result that doesn't include the text on the left. can you suggest a good regex for my problem?

Comment: i have edited my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you might do to get your result is to 2 capture in a group 2 times any character followed by a newline followed by capturing the price in a group.

```
(.+\n.+\n)(\d+\.\d{1,2})
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jyxu2i/1)

**Explanation**

- `(.+\n.+\n)` Capture in a group matching 2 times 1+ characters followed by a newline
- `(\d+\.\d{1,2})` Capture in a group matching 1+ digits followed by a dot and 1+ digits

For example:

```
const regex = /(.+\n.+\n)(\d+\.\d{1,2})/g;
let products = [];

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    products.push([m[1].replace(/\n/g, ''), m[2]]);
}
```

```js
let str = `RETAIL
UPRICE QTY TOTAL
ILLUSTRATION BOARD 15X20 (1/4 SIZE ) BY
1276
12.50 1.0 12.50
MONGOL PENCIL 1,2,3 PC
434
6.50 1.0 6.50
MS 300 (MGK) PERMANENT MARKER
1470
3.75 1.0 3.75
HBW White Glue 40 grans
1690
10.00 1.0 10.00
COLOR PEN 8 COLORS (VARIOUS BRAND)
1930
16.50 1.0 16.50
KS /CREATION CONSTRUCTION PAPER (105)
3503
23.00 1.0 23.00`;

const regex = /(.+\n.+\n)(\d+\.\d{1,2})/g;
let products = [];

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }
  products.push([m[1].replace(/\n/g, ' '), m[2]]);
}

console.log(products);
```

Comment: good day! i have tried and tested your given sample code. but with my given sample text above, i have not included the strings before the products so when i use your example all the string above or before the actual product name are also displayed as the "RETAIL"

Comment: @baattexx I have updated my answer to get 2 lines followed by matching only the price.

Comment: The result is in the products array. This array consists of  arrays where the first item is the product and the second is the price. If you loop that array, you can take the first item from the array which has index 0 in a zero based index and display that.